# Left pad a 1D column vector with 0s

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

how to convert reshape 1D numpy array to 2D numpy array
and fill with zeroes on the columns.

For example:

Input:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
```

Expected output:

```
np.array([[0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 2],
          [0, 0, 3]])
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: i may be very idiotic. but what I am trying to do is I am trying to convert an image [8 * 8] into [ 8 * 8 * 3] dimension

Comment: Not clear the question. What's your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
```

**Option 1**
`np.pad` (this should be fast)

```
np.pad(a[:, None], ((0, 0), (2, 0)), mode='constant')

array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 3]])
```

---

**Option 2**
Assign a slice to `np.zeros` (also very fast)

```
b = np.zeros((3, 3))
b[:, -1] = a

array([[0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 2.],
       [0., 0., 3.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
a.resize([3, 3])
a = np.rot90(a, k=3)
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @johnmin Nah, I don't recommend this, it's got too many operations.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that creates a zero array of m x n x 3 dimensionality. Then go through your original matrix and assign its values to those parties of the new zero matrix that should be non-zero.

Comment: I can do that.. any shortcuts for this.